# Debugging 2 applications in PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have 2 applications running on a single PHP container. Applications communicate with each other over HTTP using cURL

The xdebug configuration is:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/php5-xdebug.log
```

I use PhpStorm as my IDE, and it works perfectly if I try to debug each app separately (I have also set simultaneous connections to 3, but obviously it didn't help)

What I want to do is to test an E2E scenario, which means I'll start the debug process with one project, and when the API call is made, I'd continue the debug process in the other project's window.

I couldn't find a solution for that so far, plus PhpStorm only allows me to select a single project for the debug process (image attached).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

[image: phpStorm example: Select a project to debug]